# App crashes with reason Assertion failure in void PushNextClassForSettingIMP(id, SEL)() in >= iOS 9.3.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, crash

App crashing with the below reason when we set backgroundColor or font to UILabel
Below is the crash log

```
*** Assertion failure in void PushNextClassForSettingIMP(id, SEL)(), /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3505.16/UIAppearance.m:757
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Please file a radar on UIKit if you see this assertion.'
```

This started happening in iOS 9.3.1

This crashing for the below line.

```
[self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Please find the attached crash screenshot[image: Crash Log]

Below is the crash screenshot
[image: Crash]

Comment: I suggest you follow the error message recommendation and file a bug on https://bugreport.apple.com . My only other suggestion is to make sure the code is running on the main queue.

Comment: what type of class is MGAsynchImageView? means UIView or UIViewController ?

Comment: Its a UIView subclass @Rushi

Comment: @RoboticCat Code is running in main thread and its not crashing every time. Its happening rarely and its difficult to reproduce crash

Comment: Had a crash with `PushNextClassForSettingIMP` that was caused by running unit test with an 'All Exceptions' breakpoint.